# How were or How was?

Tags: grammar

I'm in trouble with the following sentence:

> How **was/were** the meals you had while you were gone?

I think "*How were*" is correct, but why is *"How was"* wrong?

Please explain.

Answer (score 2):

Use "were" in this case, because you're asking about "meals" in the plural.  You would use "was" for a singular subject.